# Exclude lowest ranking team and repeat the process

Tags: sqlite

The following are the first few rows of a SQLite table which is from a league-based championship:

```
+---------+-------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------------+
| EventID | Round |  HomeTeam   | HomeTeamScore | AwayTeam | AwayTeamScore |
+---------+-------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------------+
|    1210 |     1 | GERMANY     |            16 | AUSTRIA  |             4 |
|    1210 |     1 | ICELAND     |            10 | BELARUS  |            10 |
|    1210 |     1 | FINLAND     |            12 | FRANCE   |             8 |
|    1210 |     1 | NETHERLANDS |            11 | WALES    |             9 |
|    1210 |     1 | ROMANIA     |            10 | NULL     |             0 |
+---------+-------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------------+
```

I can query the final standings with:

```
SELECT 
  team, 
  SUM(vp) AS TotalVP 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      hometeam AS Team, 
      hometeamvp AS VP 
    FROM 
      matchresults 
    WHERE 
      eventid = 1210 
      AND team IS NOT NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
      awayteam AS Team, 
      awayteamvp AS VP 
    FROM 
      matchresults 
    WHERE 
      eventid = 1210 
      AND team IS NOT NULL
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  team 
ORDER BY 
  totalvp DESC;
```

which outputs:

```
+--------+---------+
|  Team  | TotalVP |
+--------+---------+
| FRANCE | 498     |
| MONACO | 487     |
| NORWAY | 486     |
| ...    | ...     |
+--------+---------+
```

(IS NOT Null is needed because odd number of teams entered the tournament) However, that is where my SQL skills end. How can I perform the following (which are, I believe, progressively more challenging):

1. Get the final standings ignoring the matches played against a certain team. (For example: Team FINLAND is disqualified. Now we should a team's match score against FINLAND should be ignored/excluded. And do not display that team in the standings.
2. Get the final standings ignoring the matches played against the lowest scoring team. This time, display the ignored team (the teams's score should be 0).
3. (This one is way above me.) Suppose there are 10 teams competing in the tournament. The above requirement, (2), will display 10 teams where the matches played against the lowest ranking team are ignored and the lowest ranking team is also displayed with score 0. Now repeat the exact same procedure with the remaining 9 teams. Thus, this time there will be again 10 teams displayed but lowest ranking two teams have score 0. How do I automate the repetition of this process?

Comment: Is it possible to improve the design of the table(s)? That home team and/or away team can be missing is an indication that there is something wrong with the design.

Comment: @Lennart When there are odd number of teams, the odd team at each round is assigned a certain score. That odd team is assigned as the HomeTeam and the AwayTeam is assigned as NULL.

Comment: If everyone gets that score sooner or later I fail to see the point. Anyhow, so the home-team is mandatory and eventid + hometeam primary key?

Comment: @Lennart The actual database is an MS Access dump from an actual championship. The database had 9 tables. And the above table had 15 fields. And to my knowledge this table had no assigned primary key.